# Vulkan compute shader outputs black lines on frames when on macOs if workgroup size is at maximum of 1024 invocations

Tags: c++, macos, graphics, vulkan, compute-shader

I'm currently working on a small SDF based graphics engine that uses compute shaders to calculate the pixel colours from data provided via storage buffers.

I've encountered a weird problem where the frames rendered by my compute shader render black lines, like so (the green pixels are correct, showing green to see the black lines better):

[image]

I've isolated a minimal example of glsl code that produces this issue, commented for clarity. The issue occurs during traversal of my spatial acceleration data structure, a bounding interval hierarchy. The only part that's relevant for the issue is, that i'm extracting booleans from flags set in the first bits of a `bounding interval link` integer.

```c
// relevant struct definition of a bounding interval
struct bounding_interval
{
    uint link;
    uint target;
    float coordinate;
};


// compute work group dimensions
layout(local_size_x = 32, local_size_y = 32) in;

// push constants provide window size and scene bounding box
layout(push_constant) uniform constants
{
    uvec2 window_size;
    vec2 scene_lower_bound;
    vec2 scene_upper_bound;
};

// relevant input buffer
...
layout(set = 0, binding = 3) buffer _tlbih { bounding_interval tlbih[]; };

// output image
layout(set = 1, binding = 0, rgba8_snorm) uniform writeonly image2D output_image;



// checks if the query point is within the scene bounding box
// the scene bounding box is provided by push constants
bool point_is_within_scene (vec2 point)
{
    return point.x > scene_lower_bound.x && point.x < scene_upper_bound.x && point.y > scene_lower_bound.y && point.y < scene_upper_bound.y;
}


// checks if the query point is to the left of the bounding interval border
bool point_is_left_in_tlbi (vec2 point, uint index)
{
    return point[ (tlbih[index].link & 0x40000000) >> 30 ] < tlbih[index].coordinate;
}


// checks if the query point is directly on the bounding interval border
bool point_is_center_in_tlbi (vec2 point, uint index)
{
    return point[ (tlbih[index].link & 0x40000000) >> 30 ] == tlbih[index].coordinate;
}


// checks if the current bounding interval is "left" or "right"
bool current_tlbi_is_right (uint index)
{
    return bool(tlbih[index].link & 0x20000000);
}


// checks if a query point intersects a bounding interval
bool point_intersects_tlbi (vec2 point, uint index)
{
    return ((point_is_left_in_tlbi(point, index) || point_is_center_in_tlbi(point, index)) && !current_tlbi_is_right(index)) || ((!point_is_left_in_tlbi(point, index) || point_is_center_in_tlbi(point, index)) && current_tlbi_is_right(index));
}


// checks if the current bounding interval is a "leaf" and therefore points to a primitive shape
bool current_tlbi_is_leaf (uint index)
{
    return bool(tlbih[index].link & 0x80000000);
}


// supposed to iterate over bounding interval hierarchy and output a colour
// removed most irrelevant code
vec4 determine_pixel_colour (vec2 point)
{
    vec3 colour = vec3(0.0);
    uint current_tlbi = 0;

    if ( !point_is_within_scene( point )) return vec4(colour, 1.0);

    while (true) {

        colour.x = 0.0;

        if ( point_intersects_tlbi( point, current_tlbi )) {

            // the issue only appears once this nested if statement is added
            if ( current_tlbi_is_leaf( current_tlbi )) {
                colour.x = 1.0;
            }

            return vec4(colour, 1.0);
        }
        else {
            return vec4(colour, 1.0);
        }
    }
}


// calculates the pixel coordinates based on the compute thread ids
ivec2 determine_pixel_coordinates ()
{
    return ivec2( clamp(gl_LocalInvocationID.xy + gl_WorkGroupID.xy * 32, ivec2(0), window_size) );
}



void main()
{
    ivec2 coordinates = determine_pixel_coordinates();

    // flips y coordinate so y+ is up, not down
    ivec2 y_inverted_coordinates = ivec2( coordinates.x, window_size.y - coordinates.y );
    vec2 point = (2.0 * y_inverted_coordinates - window_size) / float(window_size.y);

    vec4 pixel_colour = determine_pixel_colour(point);

    // adds green colour to make black lines visible
    pixel_colour += vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);

    imageStore(output_image, coordinates, pixel_colour);
}
```

**What I've determined so far:**

1. The very same code does NOT create the same black lines on my desktop windows pc (nvidia gtx 1080 ti) --> the issue occurs on my Macbook Pro (running macOs, therefore requiring moltonVK to run vulkan)
2. The issue does NOT occur when that nested if statement (marked by comment) in `determine_pixel_colour` is not presented
3. The issue does NOT occur when the `current_tlbi_is_leaf` function is called in the outer if statement
4. The amount of black lines is equal to the amount of work groups on the vertical axis. So each compute workgroup (32 x 32 threads) returns the correct colour for the first half, then returns black for the second half
5. The issue does NOT occur when the boolean is determined based on hardcoded values e.g. `bool(2147483648 & 0x80000000)` works fine --> is the buffer access the problem?

**Question:**

- is this a moltonVK issue (due to it only happening on my mac device)?
- is this a buffer access issue (due to the boolean not being a problem when using some hardcoded number)?
- could this be a present mode issue (macOS version uses FIFO, windows version uses Mailbox)?

---------- **Update 1** ----------

I discovered that this issue does not occur, when I set the local workgroup size to 16 * 16 invocations. While this would technically fix the issue, I still do not understand, why 32 * 32 invocations fail to render half of themselves. The maximum work group invocations of my macbook is set to 1024 - so my invocation count does not exceed this maximum.

---------- **Update 2** ----------

When choosing 16 * 16 * 4 invocations as a local size in my compute shader and therefore achieving the same invocation count as 32 * 32, the same issue occurs. It seems to be an issue that only occurs, when my local invocation count equals the maximum specified by the device used.

Comment: Are you using validation layers? Do they tell you anything?

Comment: @nicolBolas yes, and no, no hint from validation layers

Comment: Keep deleting stuff until you arrive at a minimal example, and then share that (unless that process already helped you find the problem). If point is to make a green screen, then make a shader that just writes green and none of that cruft.

Comment: @krOoze yeah, sorry about that. I‘ll do that if this issue becomes relevant to others in the future. Right now it‘s „fixed“ by reducing the local workgroup size… anything equal to the maximum size specified in the device properties causes the issue.

Comment: @chribit IMHO, should always be done before asking stranger's eyes and time on it (as well as pretty much mandated by SO rules). BTW I feel the `clamp` should be `wnd_size-1`, or it could be OOBA.